# Assume that $a\equiv b \mod{n}$ and that $n\mid a$. Show that $n\mid b$:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to show the following.

Assume that $a\equiv  b \mod{n}$ and that $n\mid a$. Show that $n\mid b$

Here is what I have.

If $a\equiv  b \mod{n}$ this implies $a=b+xn$ for some $x\in\mathbb Z$. (1)

Since $n\mid a$ we can say $a=yn$ for some $y\in\mathbb Z$. (2)

Combining (1) and (2) we have $yn=b+xn$ (3)

Dividing (3) by $n$ we have that $n\mid b$ (4).

Is this correct? Can I divide like this in line (4) in this kind of proof?

Comment: Your argument is sound, but you might first rearrange (3) to $b=n(y-x)$ to make it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost correct, you simply take $yn=b+xn$ and subtract $xn$ on both sides to get $b=yn-xn=n(y-x)$ which shows that $b$ is divisible by $n$.